# Need a working example of Angular 2 upgrade using two-way bindin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

The document:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#using-angularjs-component-directives-from-angular-code

says the following:

As a two-way binding:

```
<my-component [(myValue)]="anExpression">
```

In my case the ng-1.5 component uses the two-way binding, so that a simple one-way binding cannot be substituted. I'm trying to write a ng2 wrapper.

```
<ng2-wrapper [(source)]="ng2Value"></ng2-wrapper>
```

However ng2Value is never updated, even though source is changed within the component. Ng2WrapperComponent has '@Input source' and I've tried variations which include an '@Output sourceChange', but cannot come up with anything that updates ng2Value.

Does anyone have a working example?

Comment: Can you add plunker?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an working example from my collegue:

**angularJsWrapperComponent.ts (your new Angular component):**

```
...
template: `
    <angular-js-component
      [(canDeactivate)]="this.canDeactivate">
    </angular-js-component>`
...

export class AngularJsWrapperComponent implements {
private canDeactivate: boolean;
...
```

**angularJsWrapperComponentDirective.ts:**

```
...
@Directive({ selector: 'angular-js-component' })
export class AngularJsComponentWrapperDirective extends UpgradeComponent {
  @Input() canDeactivate: boolean;
  @Output() canDeactivateChange: EventEmitter<boolean>;

  constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, injector: Injector) {
    super('originalAngularJsComponent', elementRef, injector);
  }

}
...
```

**originalAngularJsComponent.ts (your AngularJs component that you want to upgrade):**

```
...
bindings: {
        canDeactivate: '='
    }
...
```